# Do C++ function templates encourage weaker typing?

Tags: c++

I started learning C++ by reading *Accelerated C++ practical programming by example* and got stuck on function templates. I understand what they do... and why they might be useful at times. But I also find them a bit inelegant and even confusing for the caller, let me explain.

The book first defines a function:

`vector<string> split(string& s)` which maps `"hello world"` to a vector with entries `hello` and `word`.

Then, the author claims that we can make our function more flexible and let the caller choose a different container (a `list` instead of a vector for example) and for this, they propose the following:

```
template <class Out> void split(const string& str, Out os)
```

My questions are,

1. How do I know... as a caller that Out must be an `iterator`? it could literally be anything.
2. If I somehow figure out it takes an iterator, I still don't know which kind.. `input` `output` `forward` `sequential` etc.

To figure these things out I would need to take a look into the function and see what operators are used in the iterator (`++`,`>`,`=`).
As a "user" of the function I should care about `what` it does... not `how` it does it.

Function templates seem to encourage a weaker form of typing.
While writing this, I realized that this question might have little to do with C++ and more to do with my inexperience using weaker typed languages, but I'll let you be the judge of that.

Comment: This is one of the primary motivations behind C++20's Concepts.

Comment: For the record, template instances are actually statically typed. The type is fixed when you compile. So theoretically, somebody writing a competent template would use something like `static_assert` and `enable_if` to ensure a template type is indeed what they want. [Concepts](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concepts) is supposed to address that particular issue in C++20.

Comment: Naming can help a lot, `Out` indeed is not informative, rename it to `OutPutIterator` and you don't need to look at implementation.

Comment: @ZuodianHu Thanks for the clarification, the name `function templates` suddenly clicked for me. Also, for the people voting `close()` could you please add a reason why you think this question should be closed?

Comment: Re: "How do I know... as a caller that Out must be an iterator?" -- read the documentation. Which is what you should be doing anyway.

Comment: @PeteBecker Fair enough. I didn't know that was the C++ philosophy. In other languages, the code itself is more self-explanatory and can do with little or no docs.

Comment: @FRR -- "self-documenting code" is usually not. That's not "C++ philosophy"; it's sound engineering. You can guess at what some code does by looking at names of things, but if you want to be sure, you need documentation.

Comment: Documentation is good, I'm not arguing that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> How do I know... as a caller that Out must be an iterator? it could technically be anything!

That's the question to the documentation or the author of code. Good template functions verify if type provided meets expectations. It can be done e.g. by a couple of `static_assert`s to ensure `Out` meets expectations. Standard library [`<type_traits>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/type_traits) offers a number of tests, which can be performed on types to check them.
Or you could just name the template parameter a bit more verbosely:

```
template <class OutputIterator> void split(const string& str, OutputIterator os)
```

Now noone should have any doubt what type is expected.

> Template functions seem to encourage dynamic typing.

There is no dynamic typing in C++. All template parameters are resolved at compile time. Compiler knows perfectly well what type is `Out` when it compiles each call to `split`.

> If I somehow figure out it takes an iterator, I still don't know which kind.. input output forward sequential etc.

Again, this is the question to the author/documentation. If you write such a function, it's best to make sure the template type is what you expect with `static_assert`, however testing existence of operator overloads might be difficult.

Comment: Maybe worth mentioning type traits here.

Comment: +1 Thanks for the clear answer! This makes a lot of sense. I have to say I prefer the Java/Kotlin approach, where the code is self-explanatory and doesn't rely on naming and documentation.

Comment: @FRR As mentioned in comments, C++20 will introduce concepts, which will enable formalization of certain requirements. Java started from a different approach - everything is an object, every function is `virtual`, no operator overloading, so the most obvious solution is to create interface `Iterator` and have all iterators inherit from it. In C++ it would be deemed wasteful to have such interface (and it discriminates raw pointers, which are the simplest `RandomAccessIterator`).

Comment: "In C++ it would be deemed wasteful to have such interface" could you elaborate on this?. I'm still very new to C++ so I'll take your word for it, I trust things will start to make more sense as I get more used to working with the language :)

Comment: @FRR C++ has the "you pay for what you use" philosophy, Java doesn't care about tiny improvements if it would result in simpler code. `virtual` functions have a cost of increasing class size and additional lookups (both are runtime costs). Due to that, STL library was designed using "conceptual" interfaces (no idea what is the actual name for that) - all containers follow certain conventions, which are not directly forced with abstract functions. Same with iterators - they are all following convention of given class, but these requirements are not forced to avoid extra costs.

Answer (score 2):

Templates in C++ *are* ***statically*** typed. The type is decided at compile time. If you pass something to a template function which it cannot use the compiler will complain and you'll get an error about an invalid template argument (or similar).

To make templates (more) ***strongly*** typed you can use template metaprogramming to prevent templates compiling outright, even if *technically* they could, for example you could pass a class with a multiply operator to a template which uses `*`, it might compile but the template is only designed for `int` or `floats` (to prevent implentation defined conversion). The standard library provides utilities such as `enable_if<...>` for just this purpose.

As to your question about knowing the iterator type, a competent library programmer will use the above mentioned strong typing techniqes, along with things like `static_assert`, and documentation to specify what type it can take. But part of the beuty of templates is that it often may not matter (for example if it can use any forward iterator with `++` it can use std forward iterators, basic pointers, etc)

Comment: Thanks for calling this out, indeed, I meant weak/strong typing as opposed to dynamically/statically typing. From your answer, I understand I should get more familiar with the language to start to appreciate the niceties that function templates provide.